# Calculating iterative probability using only longs

Tags: algorithm, probability, long-integer

I am trying to calculate an iterative probability using only longs.  In other words, I know that I can calculate this probability with the closed form of P(x) = 1-(1-p)^x  when p is the probability per occurrence and x is the number of occurrences.  But I can't use floats so I can't just iteratively multiply.

The function will take x (the number of occurrences).  It will have access to global variables for the numerator and denominator of p( for example d = 100,000,000 and n1 = 500,000 for a p of 1/200).  It will then return a long , n2, for which P(iterative) = n2 / d.

I know that eventually n2 will approach d but for my purposes, it shouldn't ever really get that close. I just want to be able to do this without risking overflow and only having access to 64 bit registers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no limits on the argument values, this is impossible.

For instance, with p=99/100 and x=10, no ratio of 64 bits integers can represent the result.

And even when a ratio is feasible, you may see a serious loss of accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with the precision that you can have with say a denomitator d = 100,000,000, then rational number arithmetic will achieve what you want to do. Intermediate results in your calculations may require more than 64 bits, but in the end, you would round the final result to a numerator and denomitor of 64 bits.